# How to create multistore with multi-domain in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view

I want to create multiple stores in magento such that those stores should be based on city names for example "newyork.domain.com" and whenever those stores are created then automatically "cityname.domain.com" subdomain should be created.

I tried creating two stores one store's folder was created but for another store folder is not created in root directory.

I am kind of lost on how these things work, can somebody help me understand the concept behind this ?

Also, can somebody suggest me any plugin or customization for this ?

By the way magento version of my site is magento-1.9.0.1 community.

Thanks in advance,
Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found a link to your Problem.

Best wishes

Donny

Magento Multishop Beispiel

Anhand der folgenden Screenshots wird die Einrichtung eines Magento Multishop gezeigt. Es werden hierbei 2 Subdomains verwendet, welche exemplarisch für 2 Domains verwendet werden.

mage1.fam-wipplinger.de
mage2.fam-wipplinger.de

Beide Subdomains zeigen im Admin-Bereich auf den gleichen Magento Ordner. Es wurden 2 Root Kategorien eingerichtet. In diesem Beispiel wird die 2. Rootkategorie für die 2. Domain/Subdomain mit "neu" benannt.

1. Cache Management deaktivieren

[image: 1]

2. System > Manage Stores auswählen und neue Website anlegen

Der hier festgelegte Code ist sehr wichtig!

[image: 2]

3. Store für die zuvor angelegte Website anlegen

[image: 3]

4. Storeview für den Store anlegen

[image: 4]

5. Die angelegte Website in System > Configuration auswählen und unter Web die secure und unsecure Domain setzen

[image: 5]

6. Datei index.php bearbeiten

[image: 6]

Beachten Sie bitte die Zeile nach dem switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])  {
Hier sollte die neue Domain angegeben werden! Zudem sollte in der nächsten Zeile der festgelegte Website Code aus Punkt 2. eingefügt werden. Nachdem sicherheitshalber der Cache noch einmal geleert worden ist, sollten nun beide Shops mit beiden Domains ansprechbar sein.

Comment: Hi Donny, since the link is on an external site it might go down at any moment, please add the content from the page to your answer and add the link as source for future visitors.